# Magritte pipelines in Rmarkdown go unnecessarily know in R Studio 2023.03.1 Build 446

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, magrittr

I use two computers.
In the first I have this version, in another a older one.

When I use this version, whatever I code within a chuck, execution of the chunk will involve R Studio slowly reading each line of the chunk, and only at the very end executing the magritte pipeline. The green bar slowly go down, and when it reach the last line, it will execute the pipeline as a whole.

The same pipeline in a script is executed instantly, instead.

In my other computer, RMarkdown has not this problem.

ADDITIONAL INFO: this is surely related to me working with a big .RData

After it is loaded, even if then removed by the workplace, it will slow everything, even operations unrelated with the workplace. Many users report same experience online.

GitHub may be involved in the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I updated R Markdown to the daily (not stable) version and it is not bugged anymore.